# How to count votes live for complex polls

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm working on a project using Google app engine where I need to have users vote on a poll live, and they only have 15 seconds to submit their vote. I already have the delivery of the options working using Pusher.com, but I'm struggling to think of the right way to go about the voting.

A set of options is generated every 30-60seconds. After that votes are counted and a new set is delivered to the users, the old votes are useless and don't need to be stored. The number of options varies every time, usually around 5 but it could be up to 20 in rare occasions. Here comes the tricky part, there are also 2 sets of sub options which are all different for every main option. These however are secondary and only matter if the particular option won. Also not every main option has them. So a sample set could be this:

```
Option A    
 sub options:
 - X
 - Y
 - Z
 sub options 2
 - F
 - G
 - H

Option B
 sub options 2
 - X
 - Z

Option C

Option D
 sub options
 - sub X
 - sub Y
 - sub Z
```

At first I thought about using a simple database table but Google app engine has concurrent user limits and it gets expensive to go to the higher tiers where I would be wasting a bunch of resources like storage limit since I don't need to save the results. I need this to be scalable to a couple thousand concurrent users.

From what I read in the [Googledocumentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters) of sharded counters, it seems like they can only be integers, so I can't store an array or string, which would be ideal. (an example of a single vote data would be {'option':'2', 'sub':'0', 'sub2':'1'}) I've been playing around [here](http://%20https://cloud-playground.appspot.com/playground/p/5047322046103552/#.gitignore)  and the only idea I've come up with is to create an int counter for every possible vote combination but that just seems inefficient, there could often be over a hundred counters. Any idea of how I could set this up? Also there doesn't seem to be any documentation on how to delete a counter after the app is running.
I should also add that I'm a beginner self taught programmer and this is my first time stepping out of my comfort zone of PHP, javascript, and very simple python.

Thank you so much for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a naive solution, but you can simply store the votes in memory in when using instances of basic or manual scaling, and push them to the datastore every few seconds, thus not encountering the maximum allowed concurrent updates.